# Is there one way to alleviate roundoff errors?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

[Wikipedia about "guard bits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_digit) offers one example codes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   double a;
   int i;

   a = 0.2; 
   a += 0.1; 
   a -= 0.3;

   for (i = 0; a < 1.0; i++) 
       a += a;

   printf("i=%d, a=%f\n", i, a);

   return 0;
}
```

With my zen2 r7 4800h cpu, I compiled the above source code `Guard_digit.c` by `gcc Guard_digit.c -std=c17 -march=znver2 -pedantic -O0 -o With_Guard_digit.o`. Then it outputs same as wikipedia `i=54, a=1.000000`.

And as this [note](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html) says, IEEE standard has implemented the guard digit:

> The IEEE standard requires the use of 3 extra bits of less significance
> than the 24 bits (of mantissa) implied in the single precision
> representation.
>
> mantissa format plus extra bits:
>
> ```
> 1.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   0   0   0                                                                                                                                          
>
> ^         ^                 ^   ^   ^
> |         |                 |   |   |
> |         |                 |   |   -  sticky bit (s)
> |         |                 |   -  round bit (r)
> |         |                 -  guard bit (g)
> |         -  23 bit mantissa from a representation
> -  hidden bit
> ```

Q: Is there one way to solve with this precision and roundoff problem by changing the source codes or others (i.e. the error offset can be **alleviated** to some degree so that it may output something like `i=108, a=1.000000`)?

Edit after viewing the answer by Eric Postpischil:

Sorry for unclearly describing the problem. I want to know how to solve the roundoff problem by keeping the original calculations, so directly `a = 0;` is not taken in account.

I want to solve this specific problem, but not general. This is beyond my current range just as the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709959/is-there-one-way-to-alleviate-roundoff-errors/76712236#comment135245352_76712236) says.

Comment: What *is* the problem you're having? Please try to make your questions *self-contained*, so we don't need to go to external links (which may disappear, or its contents change) to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have updated the question description.

Comment: `long double` with `double` constants required one iteration more, with `long double` constants exceeded allowed processing time on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f7axK8Evh)… Still I'd assume that the programme would not run endlessly, just accumulating the error until reaching 1.0 took too long.

Comment: Thanks. I got it, maybe it is difficult to achieve the endless loop like solving the problem by hand. It is the internal property of floating point that decides the not endless result.

Comment: Interesting enough: Couldn't reach 1e-4950L (1e-4951L was rounded to zero constant already) either, and finally `printf("%d\n", a == 0.0L);` wrote `1` to console – at least these values don't seem to fail with long double – still I expect we might find others that *do* (I'd assume here the equivalent to rounding 0.0000_90_ to 0.000 while if we had one digit more we'd get 0.0001 != 0.0).

Comment: @Aconcagua if the long-double version would terminate, it could not take more iterations than the length of the significant plus 1. For some constants the rounding errors (when representing decimals as binary) will just cancel out and `a==0.0` exactly before the loop.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, I also found it. I have debugged the assembly code of yours with long double, the compiler just stores some **special** values in the data area which is loaded into the `st` register stack in the `x86` architecture by something like `fld    TBYTE PTR [rip+0xe89]` so that `a` can be cancelled to `0.0` after `a -= 0.3L;` ( It is that case at least with `gcc 13.1.1` on my archlinux machine).

Comment: @zg c, Rather than `printf("i=%d, a=%f\n", i, a);`, use `printf("i=%d, a=%f %a\n", i, a, a);` to more clearly see what is happening.

Comment: It's wise to consider all floating point values to be approximations. As this example shows, often one can't even be confident of the percentage error in a result. While a and b might both have 24 bits of precision, a+b could be 100% noise. If you need exactness, you can use integers. Some languages support rational numbers as a data type, but in c you have to handle them the long way with integers. Another solution is to use a radix of 10 for floats and doubles, though modern computers don't have hardware support for these types. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Decimal-Float.html

Comment: @Aconcagua @SimonGoater Thanks for the comment. 1. After using python to calculate the `long double` value stored in `.rodata` of the Aconcagua's program, I found the value stored in `st` (viewed by `info registers float` in `gdb`) is also approximation by **roundoff** and surprisingly these approximation are just be canceled. 2. Since the decimal floating is still one C2x feature, I will try it in the future. Since decimal_32 is 32 bits, it may fit in the `st` register. 3. FYI based on your comment, rational support by c++ in compile-time should handle the problem with no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: Is there one way to solve with this precision and roundoff problem by changing the source codes or others (i.e. the error offset can be **alleviated** to some degree so that it may output something like `i=108, a=1.000000`)?

In common C implementations, it is impossible to produce an `a` by adding and/or subtracting values at or above [.0625](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709959/is-there-one-way-to-alleviate-roundoff-errors#comment135245377_76712236) that will cause the loop shown to terminate after iterating more than 57 times.

This is because common C implementations use IEEE-754 binary64, also called “double precision,” for `double`, and binary64 uses 53 significant bits. This means that a value in the [binade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade) starting at .0625 is represented with a significand whose high bit has position value 2<sup>−4</sup> (.0625) and whose low bit has position value 2<sup>−56</sup> (spanning 53 bits, including both endpoints).

Adding and subtracting can carry bits to high positions, as taught in elementary school arithmetic, but can never generate non-zero bits below the lowest input position. Therefore, any result produced by adding and subtracting values greater than or equal to .0625 cannot have any non-zero bits below 2<sup>−56</sup>.

Therefore, when entering the loop after performing such arithmetic, we have one of the following cases:

- `a` is negative or zero, and the loop never terminates.
- `a` is 2<sup>−56</sup> or greater, and iterating 57 times or fewer will making it greater than 1.

> Is there one way to solve with this precision and roundoff problem by changing the source codes…

Obviously the correct result of 0.2 + 0.1 - 0.3 can be obtained by changing the source code from:

```
a = 0.2; 
a += 0.1; 
a -= 0.3;
```

to:

```
a = 0;
```

This is a common problem in computing: You cannot formally describe the general problem you want to solve by asking “How do I get a solution for **these** values?”, because then there is simple solution that is just the one answer for those values, and it does not help you generally.

Instead, you must describe the entire class of problems. For example, you could ask: “How can I write code that finds the exact decimal sum of up 30 positive and negative decimal numerals with at most three digits after the decimal point and two digits before the decimal point?”

Note further you do not wish to go too far in the other direction, making the problem fully general instead of fully specific. If the problem is to add and subtract any decimal numerals with no error, then you must write arbitrary precision arithmetic. If the problem is to add and subtract some modest number of decimal numerals with some modest number of digits, then the problem may be solvable by using `double` arithmetic with well-chosen rounding. And specific solutions may depend on the parameters you choose. So you need to characterize the problem well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. 1. I understand the "binade" you referenced and $2^{-56}$ is related with iteration times, but why do you emphasize this number "0.0625"? 2. I will try to update my question. I am learning one basic textbook "Computer Organization and Design" by David A. Patterson and John L. Hennessy (above is referenced in one chapter) and maybe solving the general problem is beyond my current range.

Comment: @zgc: .0625 is the largest power of 2 not greater than the numbers in the example, .1, .2, and .3.